# Git: Unable to discard changes due to line endings?

Tags: windows, git

"Out of the blue" I've started having this issue with a git repository that I have hosted on GitHub.

Whenever I pull a remote branch to my computer (even on the first clone of the repository) an arbitrary (?) set of files appear as "Changes not staged for commit". I am running on Windows 8.1 and using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) alongside [Git Bash](https://msysgit.github.io/) as git clients.

An examination of the changes in these files shows that nothing has changed in them, except, maybe, the line endings. I don't know how to view the line endings when diffing so can't be sure.

When I try to "discard" these changes, it simply doesn't work. `git reset --hard` simply has no effect and the changes remain in place.

Why is this happening? How can I make it go away? :)

PS - When I run `git config -l` I see `core.autocrlf=true` appear 3 times in the list.

PPS - I have a `.gitattributes` file in the root of the repository. Deleting it does not have any effect on the above symptoms. It was first added a few days ago. It's all commented out except for `* text=auto` in the beginning of the file.

**UPDATE**:

I've found the minimum steps to reproduce my issue:

1. I open a file in a text-editor, add a single space somewhere and save it.
2. The file appears under "Changes not staged for commit" (obviously).
3. I remove the single space from the file and save it.
4. The file remains under "Changes not staged for commit" even though both SourceTree's diff and Kdiff3 show that the file is binary equal to its previous version.

Please note that the file in this example had CRLF line endings before I edited it and after I edited it - I don't understand why git insists on marking the file as changed.

**UPDATE 2:**

Running `git diff --raw MyProject/app.config` where MyProject.app/config is one of the files marked as changed gives:

`:100644 100644 b960510... 0000000... M  MyProject/app.config`

The fact that the second SHA1 is all zeroes looks like a clue to me - but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the github article on [dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) you can see that setting text=auto on the .gitattributes file tells git to "handle the files in whatever way it thinks is best." Seeing that the rest of the file was commented, and you had a star on text=auto, this was applied on everything. I suppose that in your case, what git thought was best, turned out to be the wrong choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem when you set core.autocrlf after the fact. You can try [this procedure](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings) from GitHub help. Another easy solution is to just clone a new local copy of the repository, which can also be a good troubleshooting step if you're still having problems.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm trying this out now, but I still don't understand why the issue arises in the first place. As per my update - My files already have CRLF line endings, so why does git act on them this way?

Comment: **UPDATE**: The procedure did not work for me. On the 4th step I got `nothing to commit, working directory clean`. And indeed when I cloned the repo to another machine the symptoms returned.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 3**: I was able to resolve my issue by removing the .gitattributes file from the root of my repository.

The most likely suspect for having added this file into the repo in the first place is Visual Studio 2013 are per [this Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804948/inappropriately-creates-gitattributes-file).

I still don't understand why having this file (with this `core.autocrlf=true` in it) caused the behavior that I observed. If anyone has a good explanation, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.